# Combining sh:in and sh:pattern to find placeholders in definitions

Tags: shacl

I'm trying to make a property shape that can discern between a "real" definition and a placeholder for a definition as a value for skos:definition. My input tends to contain things like "", "N/A", "N.A.", "None" etc. in the definition field, and that's fine, except my shacl shape should recognize that this definition is not valid.

```
:PlaceholderForDefinition
      a sh:PropertyShape ;
      sh:path skos:definition ;
      sh:minLength 1 ;
      sh:not [sh:in ([sh:pattern "^(?!\s*n\s*/?\s*a\s*$).*"] [sh:pattern "None"])
      ] ;   
.
```

Is there a way to make the above structure work, or am I completely on the wrong track? I admit that working with a sort of regex'd blacklist is not optimal, but it should already catch 90% of the cases, which is good enough for now, and can be expanded over time.

Thanks in advance for any tips or ideas!

Comment: Can't you just replace sh:in with sh:or ?

Comment: Hi Holger, Thanks for the response; I indeed ended up using sh:or, which works. I was hoping there might be another option that I had not considered yet. However, you are correct, I will mark the issue as solved.

Answer (score 0):

sh:in uses the literal values of your list: it does not go inside of the shapes you may enter as values in your list, and does not evaluate your regular experession, so it looks at the regex as if it is just string.

as stated in the https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#InConstraintComponent w3c standard, it seems sh:in uses the literal value of your list items, which is fine if your list items are just bits of string, but it won't go into any propertyshapes you have in the list to look for constraints, but just take the literal name of the shape.

sh:or works better in this case instead of sh:in, and will evaluate the regex correctly.